# Search html using BeautifulSoup in Python

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I wrote some code to search html, but the result was not what I wanted.
some html code I would like to pull the page addresses
I want to get the word "sayfa"
Examples:

http://www.vbulletin.com.tr/vbulletin-temel-bilgiler/sayfa2

http://www.vbulletin.com.tr/vbulletin-temel-bilgiler/sayfa3

but I don't know how to do it

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" style="margin-bottom:3px">
<tr valign="bottom">
    <td class="smallfont"><a href="http://www.vbulletin.com.tr/newthread.php?do=newthread&amp;f=16" rel="nofollow"><img src="http://www.vbulletin.com.tr/images/fsimg/butonlar/newthread.gif" alt="Yeni Konu Oluştur" border="0" /></a></td>
    <td align="right"><div class="pagenav" align="right">
<table class="tborder" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" border="0">
<tr>
    <td class="vbmenu_control" style="font-weight:normal">Sayfa 1 Toplam 5 Sayfadan</td>


        <td class="alt2"><span class="smallfont" title="Toplam 100 sonuçtan 1 ile 20 arası sonuç gösteriliyor."><strong>1</strong></span></td>
 <td class="alt1"><a class="smallfont" href="http://www.vbulletin.com.tr/vbulletin-temel-bilgiler/sayfa2/" title="Toplam 100 sonuçtan 21 ile 40 arası sonuç gösteriliyor.">2</a></td><td class="alt1"><a class="smallfont" href="http://www.vbulletin.com.tr/vbulletin-temel-bilgiler/sayfa3/" title="Toplam 100 sonuçtan 41 ile 60 arası sonuç gösteriliyor.">3</a></td>
    <td class="alt1"><a rel="next" class="smallfont" href="http://www.vbulletin.com.tr/vbulletin-temel-bilgiler/sayfa2/" title="Sonraki Sayfa - Toplam 100 sonuçtan 21 ile 40 arası sonuç gösteriliyor.">&gt;</a></td>
    <td class="alt1" nowrap="nowrap"><a class="smallfont" href="http://www.vbulletin.com.tr/vbulletin-temel-bilgiler/sayfa5/" title="Sonuncu Sayfa - Toplam 100 sonuçtan 81 ile 100 arası sonuç gösteriliyor.">Son Sayfa <strong>&raquo;</strong></a></td>
    <td class="vbmenu_control" title="forumdisplay.php?f=16&amp;order=desc"><a name="PageNav"></a></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I want to take the 'href'

```
import urllib2,re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
liste=[]
domain="http://www.forumsokagi.com/peygamber-ve-evliyalarin-hayatlari/"
page = urllib2.urlopen(domain).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
soup.prettify()
for span in soup.findAll('span'):
   print span["href"]
```

Comment: From where you want to search the term '*sayfa*' ? From html source code or from url itself ?

Comment: import requests and BeautifulSoup with SoupStrainer. You'll get the desired result. Try the sample code @carms642

Comment: www.vbulletin.com.tr/vbulletin-temel-bilgiler/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for span in soup.findAll('span'):
   if span.a:
       print span.a["href"]
```

In a list comp:

```
urls = [span.a["href"] for span in soup.findAll('span') if span.a]
```

If you `print span.a` in the loop you will see `None` sometimes so you need to check `if span.a` before using `span.a["href"]` or you will get a `TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`

You could use a set comp as there are duplicated urls:

```
urls = {span.a["href"] for span in soup.findAll('span') if span.a}
```

Then search for any url you need:

```
for url in sorted(urls):
    if "sayfa" in url:
        print url
http://www.forumsokagi.com/peygamber-ve-evliyalarin-hayatlari/sayfa2/
http://www.forumsokagi.com/peygamber-ve-evliyalarin-hayatlari/sayfa3/
http://www.forumsokagi.com/peygamber-ve-evliyalarin-hayatlari/sayfa4/
http://www.forumsokagi.com/peygamber-ve-evliyalarin-hayatlari/sayfa7/

In [26]: import urllib2

In [27]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [28]: domain="http://www.forumsokagi.com/peygamber-ve-evliyalarin-hayatlari/" 
In [29]: page = urllib2.urlopen(domain).read()

In [30]: soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

In [31]: urls = {span.a["href"] for span in soup.findAll('span') if span.a}

In [32]: for url in sorted(urls):
   ....:     if "sayfa" in url:
   ....:             print url
   ....:         
http://www.forumsokagi.com/peygamber-ve-evliyalarin-hayatlari/sayfa2/
http://www.forumsokagi.com/peygamber-ve-evliyalarin-hayatlari/sayfa3/
http://www.forumsokagi.com/peygamber-ve-evliyalarin-hayatlari/sayfa4/
http://www.forumsokagi.com/peygamber-ve-evliyalarin-hayatlari/sayfa7/
```

Comment: @carms642, what does that mean?

Comment: data should not be repeated

Comment: The data is not repeated, that is why I used a set

Comment: Must be output in this way                                                     
http://www.forumsokagi.com/peygamber-ve-evliyalarin-hayatlari/sayfa2/
http://www.forumsokagi.com/peygamber-ve-evliyalarin-hayatlari/sayfa3/
http://www.forumsokagi.com/peygamber-ve-evliyalarin-hayatlari/sayfa4/
http://www.forumsokagi.com/peygamber-ve-evliyalarin-hayatlari/sayfa7/

Comment: How do I   I'm confused

Comment: The code I have written produces what you see in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import requests
domain = "http://www.forumsokagi.com/peygamber-ve-evliyalarin-hayatlari/"
page = requests.get(domain)
result = BeautifulSoup(page.text)
anc = result.findAll("span")
for values in range(len(anc)):
    anchor = anc[values].findAll('a')
    for i in anchor:
        if "javascript" not in i.get('href') and "sayfa" in i.get('href'):
            print i.get('href')
```

This will fetch you the href links.

```
Output:
http://www.forumsokagi.com/forum.php
http://www.forumsokagi.com/peygamber-ve-evliyalarin-hayatlari/sayfa2/
etc...
```

Comment: What is SoupStrainer?

Comment: Using SoupStrainer we can parse selectively @heinst.

Comment: UserWarning: The "parseOnlyThese" argument to the BeautifulSoup constructor has been renamed to "parse_only."
  'has been renamed to "%s."' % (old_name, new_name))

Comment: try parse_only instead of parseOnlyThese, check http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/ for details. The BeautifulSoup version that you use might be varying @carms642

Comment: I could not find a solution

Comment: @carms642, edited the code without using parseOnlyThese. Try this

Comment: @Sesha you might want to upgrade to `bs4`. Your code uses BeautifulSoup version 3, and when run using bs4 will give warnings and errors. For example, `findAll()` is now `find_all()`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want urls that has word **sayfa**.

You can also use `lxml` to do it.

```
import urllib2
import lxml.html
domain="http://www.forumsokagi.com/peygamber-ve-evliyalarin-hayatlari/"
data=urllib2.urlopen(domain).read()
tree = lxml.html.fromstring(data)
for i in  tree.xpath('//a/@href'):
    if "sayfa" in i:
        print i
```

Output:

```
http://www.forumsokagi.com/peygamber-ve-evliyalarin-hayatlari/sayfa2/
http://www.forumsokagi.com/peygamber-ve-evliyalarin-hayatlari/sayfa3/
http://www.forumsokagi.com/peygamber-ve-evliyalarin-hayatlari/sayfa4/
http://www.forumsokagi.com/peygamber-ve-evliyalarin-hayatlari/sayfa2/
http://www.forumsokagi.com/peygamber-ve-evliyalarin-hayatlari/sayfa7/
http://www.forumsokagi.com/peygamber-ve-evliyalarin-hayatlari/sayfa2/
http://www.forumsokagi.com/peygamber-ve-evliyalarin-hayatlari/sayfa3/
http://www.forumsokagi.com/peygamber-ve-evliyalarin-hayatlari/sayfa4/
http://www.forumsokagi.com/peygamber-ve-evliyalarin-hayatlari/sayfa2/
http://www.forumsokagi.com/peygamber-ve-evliyalarin-hayatlari/sayfa7/
```

Comment: What should I do to have the different screen output
Example:
http://www.forumsokagi.com/peygamber-ve-evliyalarin-hayatlari/sayfa2/
http://www.forumsokagi.com/peygamber-ve-evliyalarin-hayatlari/sayfa3/
http://www.forumsokagi.com/peygamber-ve-evliyalarin-hayatlari/sayfa4/
http://www.forumsokagi.com/peygamber-ve-evliyalarin-hayatlari/sayfa7/